# Discord bot python - RuntimeError can't start new thread

Tags: python, multithreading, async-await, discord, runtime-error

I'm developing a Discord bot in Python 3 and can't get it running properly. I'm hosting the bot on a 1&1 server, booting it with `nohup python3 main.py &`. The bot is running and working perfectly for a while then crash with every times a huge Traceback of errors ending with `RuntimeError: can't start new thread.`. And furthermore the source line of the error from my code isn't the same each time. It always comes from an `await [...]` line.

I've been searching for a while on internet but other developers using `import threading` and related functions while I don't, i'm only using the `async / await` keywords. Is this a mistake ? I'm certain that i don't reach the thread limit, i've been testing my bot with only a few friends, so a maximum of 3 to 4 requests at a time. The bot is using asynchronous methods only for sending messages or reactions on Discord, there is no recursion anywhere.

Here is one of the multiple Traceback i've had. Hope somebody can help me, thanks !

`

````
Ignoring exception in on_message
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/kunden/homepages/44/d758963141/htdocs/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 333, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "main.py", line 261, in on_message
    await message.channel.send(lines + "```")
  File "/kunden/homepages/44/d758963141/htdocs/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/discord/abc.py", line 905, in send
    nonce=nonce, allowed_mentions=allowed_mentions)
  File "/kunden/homepages/44/d758963141/htdocs/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/discord/http.py", line 185, in request    async with self.__session.request(method, url, **kwargs) as r:
  File "/kunden/homepages/44/d758963141/htdocs/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/aiohttp/client.py", line 1012, in __aenter__
    self._resp = await self._coro
  File "/kunden/homepages/44/d758963141/htdocs/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/aiohttp/client.py", line 483, in _request
    timeout=real_timeout
  File "/kunden/homepages/44/d758963141/htdocs/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/aiohttp/connector.py", line 523, in connect
    proto = await self._create_connection(req, traces, timeout)
  File "/kunden/homepages/44/d758963141/htdocs/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/aiohttp/connector.py", line 859, in _create_connection
    req, traces, timeout)
  File "/kunden/homepages/44/d758963141/htdocs/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/aiohttp/connector.py", line 967, in _create_direct_connection
    traces=traces), loop=self._loop)
  File "/kunden/homepages/44/d758963141/htdocs/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/aiohttp/connector.py", line 830, in _resolve_host
    self._resolver.resolve(host, port, family=self._family)
  File "/kunden/homepages/44/d758963141/htdocs/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/aiohttp/resolver.py", line 30, in resolve
    host, port, type=socket.SOCK_STREAM, family=family)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/asyncio/base_events.py", line 789, in getaddrinfo
    None, getaddr_func, host, port, family, type, proto, flags)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/asyncio/base_events.py", line 752, in run_in_executor
    executor.submit(func, *args), loop=self)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/concurrent/futures/thread.py", line 160, in submit
    self._adjust_thread_count()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/concurrent/futures/thread.py", line 181, in _adjust_thread_count
    t.start()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/threading.py", line 847, in start
    _start_new_thread(self._bootstrap, ())
RuntimeError: can't start new thread
````

`

===== EDIT =====

Here is a sample of my code :

`

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message) :
    global messagesId
    # ===== Block self messages =====
    if message.author == client.user :
        return
    # ===== $register =====
    elif message.content == "$register" :
        if not(await isRegistered(message.author.id, message.channel)) :
            try :
                refreshDb()
                sql = "INSERT INTO player VALUES (%s, %s, 0)"
                dbCurs.execute(sql, (message.author.id, message.author.name))
                sql = "INSERT INTO schedule(player_id) VALUES (%s)"
                dbCurs.execute(sql, (message.author.id))
                db.commit()
            except Exception as e :
                await message.channel.send("Erreur interne #9")
                raise e
            await message.channel.send("Tu as été enregistré.")
        else :
            await message.channel.send("Tu es déjà enregistré.")
# ===== $schedule =====
elif message.content == "$schedule" :
    # Get player's current schedule
    data = None
    try :
        if await isRegistered(message.author.id, message.channel) :
            try :
                refreshDb()
                sql = "SELECT * FROM schedule WHERE player_id = %s"
                dbCurs.execute(sql, (message.author.id))
                data = dbCurs.fetchall()[0]
            except Exception as e :
                await message.channel.send("Erreur interne #4")
                raise e
        else :
            await message.channel.send("Tu dois t'enregistrer pour utiliser cette commande.")
            return
    except Exception as e :
        await message.channel.send("Erreur interne #5")
        raise e
    # Create lines
    text = "<@{}>\n{}".format(message.author.id, getScheduleText(data, 1))
    sentMessage = await message.channel.send(text)
    # register message's id
    messagesId[sentMessage.id] = message.author.id
    # Add reactions
    i = 0
    keys = list(cols.keys())
    for key in keys :
        await sentMessage.add_reaction(bytes.decode(numbers[i]))
        i += 1
    # Register every messages id and delete everyone after 60 sec
    await deleteSched(sentMessage)
```

`

Answer (score 0):

Your code apparently *is* using threads, via a thread-pool-executor; this is intended to run long-lasting tasks but leave the main asyncio thread available to handle more events. Creating new threads in the executor will always happen when your code hits some `await` condition, as this is the only time the event loop is free to work.

So..., it seems like the tasks you are running in the executor are not ending, and you are ending up with very many stale threads. Without seeing the code, I don't think we can say more.

Comment: Hi and thank you very much for your quick answer ! i edited my post to show a part of my code (i can't just copy past over 250 lines it would be unreadable). Note that `refreshDb()` only reestablish connection if the session as timeouted.

Comment: Yeah, sorry, that's far too complicated for me to understand, and I see no obvious mention of the executor https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: No problems, but I can't really explain how to reproduce the error since I don't know how and why it happen. Have a good day !